# C++ command line interface help message wont display

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I am trying to make a CLI app in C++. This is my first time coding in C++.

I have this c++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std;

static void help(std::string argv)
{
    std::cerr << "Usage:" << argv << " [options]\n"
        << "Options:\n"
        << "-h (--help): Displays this help message.\n"
        << "-o (--output=[output file]): Specifies the output file.\n"
        << "-p (--ports=[ports]) Sets the ports to scan.\n"
        << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        std::cout << argv[1] << "\n";
        if (argv[1] == "-h" || argv[1] == "--help")
        {
            help(argv[0]);
            return 0;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "No arguments were given" << "\n";
    };
};

// g++ -o cli main.cpp
```

It works! When I compile it, it successfully outputs `No arguments were given`, but when I run `cli -h`, I can see `argv[1]` is -h, but nothing is outputted.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel [boost::program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options.html) or [argparse](https://github.com/hbristow/argparse) or anything else.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks so much! For this question, it doesn't help, but I will certainly start using those programs. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your string comparison, `argv[1]` is a C string: a null-terminated char array. You cannot compare these with `==` and get the result you expect.  If, however, you assign it to a `std::string` you can compare it with `"-h"` and `"--help"` the way you want.

```
std::string arg1 = argv[1];
if (arg1 == "-h" || arg1 == "--help") {
    help(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you could use `std::strcmp` to compare C strings without creating a new `std::string`. In order to do this, you'll need `#include <cstring>`.

```
if (std::strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0 || std::strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0) {
    help(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creating temporary strings for sake of comparison is a rather poor suggestion.

Comment: I've added an alternative approach using `std::strcmp` to correctly compare C strings.